# Get json value from response

Tags: javascript, json

```
{"id":"2231f87c-a62c-4c2c-8f5d-b76d11942301"}
```

If I alert the response data I see the above, how do I access the `id` value?

My controller returns like this:

```
return Json(
    new {
        id = indicationBase.ID
    }
);
```

In my ajax success I have this:

```
success: function(data) {
    var id = data.id.toString();
}
```

It says `data.id` is `undefined`.

Comment: How are you receiving the data? Could you show some Javascript?

Comment: `response.id` I think :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If response is in json and not a string then

```
alert(response.id);
or
alert(response['id']);
```

otherwise

```
var response = JSON.parse('{"id":"2231f87c-a62c-4c2c-8f5d-b76d11942301"}');
response.id ; //# => 2231f87c-a62c-4c2c-8f5d-b76d11942301
```

Comment: Note that this may not work on older browsers. You can use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to get around this.

Answer (score 4):

Normally you could access it by its property name:

```
var foo = {"id":"2231f87c-a62c-4c2c-8f5d-b76d11942301"};
alert(foo.id);
```

or perhaps you've got a JSON string that needs to be turned into an object:

```
var foo = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert(foo.id);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 2):

Use [safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

```
var jsonString = '{"id":"2231f87c-a62c-4c2c-8f5d-b76d11942301"}';

var jsonObject = (new Function("return " + jsonString))();

alert(jsonObject.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = {"id":"2231f87c-a62c-4c2c-8f5d-b76d11942301"}
console.log(results.id)
=>2231f87c-a62c-4c2c-8f5d-b76d11942301
```

`results` is now an object.

Answer (score 0):

If the response is in json then it would be like:

```
alert(response.id);
```

**Otherwise**

```
var str='{"id":"2231f87c-a62c-4c2c-8f5d-b76d11942301"}';
```